# Finding probability of defective item using Hypergeometric Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

For part $(b)$, the solution is from the textbook solution from the book. $k = 1$, so why did they set it up like that? Can anyone explain?

[image: picture]

Comment: It should be $\binom{1}{1}$, not $\binom{3}{1}$.  The required probability is $3/25$.

Comment: You are welcome. You were right, there is a  slip in the official answer.